# what algorithm hadoop dfs uses to store data on nodes? or it chooses nodes at random?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

How does hdfs determine which data block to be stored on which node?There must be some algorithm on choosing the data nodes for data blocks.I would like to learn about that.

Answer (score 2):

HDFS replica placement is rack aware. i.e. it will try to place replicas on different racks to allow for better reliability. There's also work to allow HDFS to run with multi-tiered storage and to run in virtualization and these will also affect the placement algorithm

You can read on the current replica placement policy in the [Hadoop architecture guide](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html#Data_Replication)